# Vim freezes with fuzzy search and wildmenu tab complete

Tags: vim

I'm trying to customize my vimrc with tips from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA2WjJbmmoM). I added these two lines to my vimrc:

```
set path+=**
set wildmenu
```

...to enable fuzzy file search. However when I try to hit tab to show results there're some issues:

1. If I try `:find *foo` (or `:find *.foo` w/ `.foo` filetype) the command line will be stuck as `:find *foo ...` after I hit tab and everything freezes.
2. The command line will be stuck similarly if I do `:find fo` and hit tab to try to autocomplete the file name.
3. The only instance where it doesn't freeze is if I open vim in the same directory as my vimrc (for me it's ~/vimfiles), here the matches will be shown in the wildmenu, but if I open any file upward of my vimfiles directory it will show up with jumbled characters.
4. The search does work if I search downward for a file with the exact name `:find foo.foo`, then `foo.foo` will open correctly. I cannot search upward in the same manner though.

Any idea as to what I can do / should know? I'm on Windows if that's relevant. Thanks.

**Edit:** after some more testing I discovered the following:

- When I do `:find *foo` from vimfiles, it actually doesn't yield all the fuzzy results possible
- Testing in a very small directory, the fuzzy search in fact *does* work, and I'm realizing that in larger directories it will also work, but only after up to 30 min ~ 1 hr depending on the directory size.

So is it the case to just not use this for larger directories?

Furthermore, is there a way to interrupt / break the execution of a command in case of freeze?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...to enable fuzzy file search

That's not "fuzzy search".

> `.foo` filetype

`.foo` is an *extension*, not a "filetype".

> So is it the case to just not use this for larger directories?

Yes. `set path+=**` means that when you ask Vim to `:find *foo`, it is going to search for a file with `foo` in its name in every directory under the working directory, which will be slower as the tree gets larger. Note that you have two bottlenecks, here, that conspire to slow things down:

- The search algorithm used by Vim for searching files has been described as "depth-first". This means (roughly) that a directory has to be fully explored before switching to the next directory, which can be a considerable time sink if you have some very deep directories.
- Building the "wildmenu" is not very efficient and it will choke hard on very large lists.

You have a few ways to improve things:

1. Set your `:help 'path'` to a sensible value that doesn't include `**`. That option is a white list, not a dumpster.
2. Use smarter queries.
3. Set a sensible `:help 'wildignore'` to lighten the wildmenu workload.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/7e2b425a1706cd85f04a0bd8b3898805) for a thorough breakdown of the situation.

> Furthermore, is there a way to interrupt / break the execution of a command in case of freeze?

Yes, see `:help <C-c>`.